# How to make a second level using Java

Tags: java, javafx

So i've built a game and so far i only have one level, I'd like to add a second level with different crate positions, diamond positions and wall positions but i'm not sure on the best approach to take.

Would you recommend i make my second level(and more) inherit my first level and alter the game code or do it in a slightly different way? Like can i just make another class called "level2" and add some code in my current game class that will make the player jumpt to level 2 on completion of level one?

```
public class Game extends Application {

    Pane backgroundPane;
    Pane playfieldLayer;
    Pane scoreLayer;

    Image playerImage;
    Image wallImage;
    Image foodImage;
    Image diamondImage;

    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Diamonds> diamonds = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean collision;
    boolean wallCollision;
    boolean foodWallCollision;
    boolean won = false;

    GridPane gameGrid;
    static Scene scene;
    Stage theStage;

    @Override

    public void start(Stage theStage) {

        // theStage.setWidth(Settings.SCENE_WIDTH);
        // theStage.setHeight(Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT);

        Menu menu = new Menu();
        Scene menuView = new Scene(menu, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT, Settings.SCENE_WIDTH);

        theStage.setScene(menuView);
        // theStage.setResizable(false);

        theStage.show();

        Menu.start.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                runGame(theStage);

            }
        });

    }

    public void runGame(Stage theStage) {

        // Input input = new Input(scene);

        Group root = new Group();

        GridPane gameGrid = new GamePane(14, 14);
        gameGrid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-grid-lines-visible:true");
        backgroundPane = new Pane();
        backgroundPane.setId("root");
        playfieldLayer = new Pane();
        scoreLayer = new Pane();

        playfieldLayer.getChildren().add(gameGrid);
        root.getChildren().add(backgroundPane);
        root.getChildren().add(playfieldLayer);

        // scene = new Scene(root, (columnAmount * 40) + 66, (rowAmount * 40) +
        // 66, Color.WHITE);

        scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);
        backgroundPane.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        // theStage.setResizable(false);
        theStage.setScene(scene);
        theStage.show();

        loadGame();

        try {

            createPlayers();
            spawnFood();
            spawnWall();
            spawnDiamonds();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            System.out.println("You are missing the pictures for the spawn methods");
        }

        AnimationTimer gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // player input
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.processInput());
                foods.forEach(sprite -> sprite.processInput());

                // movement
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.move());
                foods.forEach(sprite -> sprite.move());
                // ((Player) players).stopInput();

                // check collisions

                checkCollisions();
                // GamePane.checkWallCollisions();
                checkWallCollisions();
                checkfoodwallCollisions();
                checkDiamondCollisions();
                checkWallPlayerCollisions();
                checkWin();

                // update sprites in scene
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.updateUI());
                foods.forEach(sprite -> sprite.updateUI());

            }

        };
        gameLoop.start();

    }

    private void loadGame() {
        playerImage = new Image(getClass().getResource("warehouse.png").toExternalForm());
        wallImage = new Image(getClass().getResource("Wall.png").toExternalForm());
        foodImage = new Image(getClass().getResource("food.png").toExternalForm());
        diamondImage = new Image(getClass().getResource("Chef.png").toExternalForm());
    }

    private void createPlayers() {

        Input input = new Input(scene);

        input.addListeners(scene);

        Image image = playerImage;

        double x = (Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - image.getWidth()) / 1.5;
        double y = Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.2;

        Player player = new Player(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, 0, input);

        players.add(player);

    }

    private void spawnFood() {

        Input input = new Input(scene);

        input.addListeners(scene);

        Image image = foodImage;

        double x = (Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - image.getWidth()) / 2.0;
        double y = Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.4;

        Food food = new Food(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, input);

        foods.add(food);

    }

    private void spawnWall() {

        Input input = new Input(scene);

        input.addListeners(scene);

        Image image = wallImage;

        double x = Settings.SCENE_WIDTH * 0.01;
        double y = Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.01;

        Wall wall = new Wall(playfieldLayer, image, x, 100, 0, 0, input);
        Wall wall2 = new Wall(playfieldLayer, image, 570, 150, 0, 0, input);

        walls.add(wall);
        walls.add(wall2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            y = 200;
            x = x + 50;

            Wall wall1 = new Wall(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, input);

            walls.add(wall1);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            y = y -40;
            x = x - 50;

            Wall wall4 = new Wall(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, input);

            walls.add(wall4);

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            y = y + 150;
            x = x -100;

            Wall wall5 = new Wall(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, input);

            walls.add(wall5);

        }

    }

    private void spawnDiamonds() {

        Input input = new Input(scene);

        input.addListeners(scene);

        Image image = diamondImage;

        double x = (Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - image.getWidth()) / 3.0;
        double y = Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.1;

        Diamonds diamond = new Diamonds(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, input);

        diamonds.add(diamond);

    }

    private boolean checkCollisions() {

        collision = false;

        for (Player player : players) {
            for (Food food : foods) {
                if (player.collidesWith(food)) {

                    player.setDy(-player.getDy());
                    player.setDx(-player.getDx());

                    Food.collision = true;

                }

            }
        }
        return collision;

    }

    //other collisions exist but not added due to simplicity

    public void checkWin() {

        if (won == true) {

            System.out.println("won");

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

Comment: I would just decouple whatever you have that's general to all levels into an abstract class (call it Level for example), and have every specific level be a subclass of it. Hard coding each level as a specific class isn't good practice (what if you want to expand the game to 100 levels for example?) and involves a lot of repeated code that can be refactored into one concise location.

Comment: I second what @twist295 said. Your code is at risk of becoming a cyclomatic complexity (look it up) nightmare.

Comment: Brilliant that does seem the best way. Can i just do something like 

if player has completed the "win conditions" {
 run.level2

Comment: To add my thoughts ..You might also look into some of the design patterns that suit your need. for instance to unlock the next level, you might want to consider observer design pattern...and so on

Comment: I will take a look a cyclomatic complexity (by the way Hovercraft full of Eels for some reason i love your user name). Awesome i will take a look at some other design patterns. Thanks for the advice so far people!

my main issue in my head is how to change like the diamond and crate positions in my level 2 class based on the super class methods.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really a Java Developer, though I worked on a few Java Projects a very long time ago. Nevertheless, the following advice would apply to any object-oriented project, so it may be of some help.

- A class defines a **type** of object. If two objects are of the same type, they should be derived from the same class.
- Sometimes, you want to modified type. This you do by extending a class.
- An extended class would generally have additional properties or methods; that is it would have additional data or functionality.
- The whole point in having classes is to have multiple object with the *same* properties  and methods. The property *values* may change, but the object is still of the same type.

Given nature of your question, I am inclined to suggest:

- An additional level is probably just an additional object with different property values. I don’t imagine that you actually need a new class.
- During run time, you probably are dealing with only a single level at time, so you might even be using the same object, re-initialised with different property levels.

**Edit**

Again, I’m out of my field here, so the terminology my be wrong.

If I had a number of levels, I would probably create a descriptor class which has properties for all variable elements. Then I would create an array of objects of this class, representing the property values of each object.

Finally, I would either substantiate ore re-initialise a level using the particular array element in the constructor. Something like this:

```
level2 = new Level(levels[2]);  //  new object
//  or
level = level.init(levels[2]);  //  existing object
```

Comment: Thankyou for the advice Manngo, that's all brilliant advice. Yes you are right i suppose thinking about it I don't need a separate class for different levels. I just need to figure out a way on how to change the spawn methods to suit the different levels.

Comment: So, in theory, i could add the spawn positions of the 2nd level wall, diamond, crates to a level2 array object and call that as i need to?

Comment: I think this is what he's saying, but you should have a master level.  And then each level class you create extends this master level.  And then you can override any methods that make that level unique.

Comment: Would the best way of using your method be adding a constructor to the game class and implementing the super constructor attributes to a level 2 class?

Comment: Sorry, but this is getting out of my depth here — I’m not familiar with your code, and I don’t consider myself a Java Developer. And I’m not sure that this is necessarily the path I would follow. Anyway, my suggestion above involves a class called something like LevelAttributes, with a constructor giving it whatever attributes you need for a single level. It’s not a level in itself, but just a container for properties. Then create an array of LevelAttribute properties. Finally, your Level constructor would take the form of `Level(LevelAttributes attributes)`.